# optimum rectangle around a group of coordinates (longitude and latitude)

Tags: polar-coordinates

Okay, I am in no way a mathematics student but I happened to be writing a program on a map with coordinates of locations displayed on the map.

My problem is that the points could be scattered on the map with an indefinite boundary and I need to find a boundary (rectangle) around these points and thus I need to get a formula to form an algorithm so that the program will find the optimum boundary itself.

I hope this is understandable and thanks in anticipation of any response.

Comment: What do you mean by optimum boundary in this case? Are you trying to find a rectangle with minimum perimeter that includes all points of interest?

Comment: exactly! just like you put it. "minimum perimeter that includes all points of interest"

Answer (score 2):

If the sides of the rectangle must be aligned with the edges of the map, you can just take the maximum and minimum coordinates in each direction.  If you allow arbitrary orientation of the rectangle you have a one dimensional minimization problem.  You can compute the coordinates of each point as a function of rotation angle, again take the maximum and minimum in each dimension, calculate the perimeter, and minimize over the rotation angle.

If you are not devoted to a rectangle, maybe you would prefer the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your points.  There are efficient algorithms to find it and it doesn't need the minimization.  It also has a smaller perimeter yet.